# karate and report portal integration

Tags: karate

@peter Thomas Not sure if you have seen/heard of reportportal - https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal. This is interesting and It would be great if karate integrates with it. I also saw some one raising an issue there - https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-cucumber/issues/18.  I will try integrating and let you know and I am just suggesting something to you which can be a good value add. Your thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well we are deprecating the TestNG runner so that may be an issue unless there is community contribution: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1025067559027179521